# Run executable after jenkins pipeline build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a console application that needs to be permanently running on the same machine on which I run Jenkins. After I build and publish the `.exe` file I need to run it but if I try to use `bat "pathtofile\\filename.exe"`, the pipeline will wait for the process to finish, but it never will because the process is a socket server which keeps running and listening.

Is there a way to Run a Fire-and-Forget command to start the .exe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a [Windows Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service)? If this is not an option, I would suggest using the `/B` flag of the `start` command. For example,

```
start /B yourapp.exe
```

will execute your app in the background, somewhat similar to Linux's `yourapp &` command form.

To check out all the options of the `start` command, you can type `help start` in a Command Line Window.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins gives guidance and examples on this for freestyle projects (but the principle should be the same for pipeline), see:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build

For Windows, there are a number of options - using the `at` command (runs a job at specific time); creating a wrapper script to run your `bat` file; or creating a scheduled task (thus similar to the `at` command). I've used the schedule task approach (again for freestyle builds rather than pipeline).